# OSX find command with partial filename

Tags: macos, terminal

I understand that within the osx terminal the command `find . -name 'filename.type'` will find me and return to me files of that exact name. However, I am wondering if there is any command which i could use to search for partial filenames.

For example. Say I have a bunch of images that are named sequentially as 'IMG_01', 'IMG_02', etc. Is there a command by which I could search a directory/directories for all files containing 'IMG' in the filename from the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$ find . -name "IMG_*" -print
```

The `find` man page gives directions about how shell metacharacters can be used with the -name option, so if you really wanted to find only the ones with two numeric digits you could with

```
$ find . -name "img_[0-9][0-9]" -print
./img_03
```